# ReactJS: Can I separate a function that changes state in a separate component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've got a function in my React app that is calling in `componentWillMount` lifecycle method.
It grabs data from JSON file and push it to the component's state (it is a text data, I later insert that text into the page).

I'm going to use the same function on many other components, can I separate this function into a separate component to make it reusable?

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';
import logo from '../img/company_logo.png';
import '../css/header.scss';
import getTextData from './getTextData';


const NumberList = (props) => {
  console.log(props.value);

  const itemList = props.value;

  const listItems = itemList.map(number => (
    <li key={number.toString()}>
      {number}
    </li>
  ));
  return (
    <ul>{listItems}</ul>
  );
};

export default class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    axios.get('./data.json')
      .then((res) => {
        this.setState({
          siteData: res.data,
        });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }

  render() {
    // console.log(this.state);
    const { siteData } = this.state;

    if (siteData) {
      console.log(siteData.data.mainPage.navBar);
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    return (
      <div className="headerWrapper">
        <a href=".../public/index.html"><img src={logo} alt="company_logo" id="companyLogo" /></a>
        <NumberList value={siteData.data.mainPage.navBar} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, create a function and return the repsonse-data, `must use async await`

```
//fetchService.js
    import axios from 'axios';
    export default async function fetchService(){
       let responseData = [];    
       await axios.get('./data.json')
          .then((res) => {
             responseData = res.data;
          })
          .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
          });
       return responseData;
    }
// App.js
import fetchService from './fetchService';
 async componentDidMount() {
    let tempData = await fetchService();
     this.setState({
          siteData: tempData,
     });
  }
```

i hope this helps!

Comment: can you explain why it should be `async await`? I will very appreciate that :)

Comment: javascript is asynchronous language, so, `return responseData` can execute before `axios.get() execution`, when we use [async/await](https://codeburst.io/javascript-es-2017-learn-async-await-by-example-48acc58bad65) it resolves promises and wait for the response. It is non blocking (just like promises and callbacks).

Comment: thank you, now it's more clearly for me. Also a question about `this.setState` part - we don't have responseData defined in `App.js`, will it throws an error?

Comment: @Karen updated the answer, you can use any variable name

Comment: *It is non blocking (just like promises* - it is a promise, not just like a promise. You likely miss something about async-await. You *can* use it, not *must*. Why do you use `await` together with `then` then?